# Drupal query not updating

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6

```
<?php
$search = array('.pdf', '.', '-', '_');
$replace = array('', '/', '</u>- ', ' ');
$query="SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(`filename`, 1, 10),'%m.%d.%Y') as filedate, `filename`, `filepath`
FROM  `files`  
WHERE `filepath` LIKE 'sites/default/files/news/%' 
ORDER BY filedate DESC
LIMIT 4";
$results = db_query($query);

while ($row = db_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><u><a href=http://website.com/sites/default/files/news/'. $row["filename"] . '>' . str_replace($search, $replace, $row["filename"]) . '</a></td><br />';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

I have this code on the homepage of my website. It pulls all files in a certain folder that start with a date. Currently, when I add a new file, the query doesn't update, even though when I run the query in PHPmyadmin it works fine.

What's happening to make the query not update itself? Flushing cache's haven't worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your not trying to update, your pulling data from the database.

I would suggest you use `file_scan_directory`.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/7

```
<?php
$files = file_scan_directory('/sites/default/files/news', '/.*\.pdf$/');
foreach ($files as $file) {
  print $file->filename;
}
?>
```

Above code is not directly tested.

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong term. Is this the only way? Is there a way to have drupal pull from the database again?

Comment: Sure you can pull from the database, but when i look at your code, all your actually trying to do is list file from a folder. With the above code you can do exactly the same only not having to connect to the database.